# How to select multiple rows as multiple rows using for json path

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, for-json

If I do this:

```
SELECT *
FROM someTable
FOR JSON PATH
```

I get a single result.

I want each row of the table to output as a separate row containing the json for just that row.

Can that be done?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this as a nested subquery. `WITHOUT_ARRAY_WRAPPER` will remove the `[]` around the JSON also

```sql
SELECT
  json = (
    SELECT p.*
    FOR JSON PATH, WITHOUT_ARRAY_WRAPPER
  )
FROM someTable p;
```

Comment: even more better - thank you

Answer (score 0):

Never mind. I figured it out.

```
SELECT (SELECT *
        FROM someTable
        WHERE someUniqueColumn = p.someUniqueColumn
        FOR JSON PATH)
FROM someTable p
```

Comment: `SELECT (SELECT p.* FOR JSON PATH)
FROM someTable p`

Comment: Even better - cheers